# Error on SIMPLE ANDROID OCR

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error, ocr, tess-two

When I tried the *Simple Android OCR* (https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR) in **ANDROID STUDIO** it gave me a runtime error as shown in the picture. Can anyone help me with this?

![Runtime error occured when tried to run][2]

```
06-03 12:44:31.904  17051-17051/com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera, PID: 17051
android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera/com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2333)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr

Comment: make sure you got this `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` right after your `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar read the question before posting links. the issue is not the lib, it's a missing call in onCreate.

Comment: @Strider Thanks man... It did the trick.

But Still, when running, a blank page opens up. Show none of my XML components

Comment: These are the Errors

Comment: `06-03 14:07:17.681  22012-22012/com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera E/Zygote﹕ Zygote:  error closing descriptor
    libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
            at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)`

Comment: `at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:224)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:704)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: also
`06-03 14:07:17.798  22012-22012/com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera E/﹕ appName=com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
06-03 14:07:17.798  22012-22012/com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera E/﹕ 0
06-03 14:07:17.798  22012-22012/com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera E/﹕ appName=com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
06-03 14:07:17.798  22012-22012/com.startup.vrvijay.liccamera E/﹕ 0`

Comment: @VRVijay post a new question and include your code.

Comment: @Strider you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @rmtheis yeah you're right, i've done it now, just in case someone else got the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to place:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

right after your

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```